# When did windows start to support [System.BitConverter]

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a powershell script which has to call [System.BitConverter], I want to make sure it run correctly in Windows server 2008, 2012, 2019.

I do not have windows server 2008 right now, I was wondering when windows started to support [System.BitConverter]

Comment: `[BitConverter]` has been around since at least .NET Framework 1.1, but Server 2008 doesn't ship with PowerShell FWIW

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netcore-3.1 it comes with .Net 1.0   seems .Net 1.0 is used since windows server 2000 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history So System.BitConverter is supported since windows 2000, correct?

Comment: Windows PowerShell comes installed by default in every Windows, starting with Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7

Comment: `.NET Framework 4.6.2`  is supported on Windows Server 2008, you are able to use the `[System.BitConverter]` class from that point on.